# mysql - Foreign Key Constraint Fails

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Hi I know this has been asked but I haven't found the correct answer, how come when I try to do my second insert:

```
INSERT INTO phone_numbers (phone_number) VALUES ('226');
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`week7`.`phone_numbers`, CONSTRAINT `phone_numbers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

DDL CODE BELOW:

```
create table users (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(id)
);

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('alex');


create table phone_numbers (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  user_id int unsigned not null,
  phone_number varchar(25) not null,
  primary key(id),
  foreign key (user_id) references users (id)

);

 INSERT INTO phone_numbers (phone_number) VALUES ('226');
```

Comment: You have to provide and existing user_id in the insert. You seem to have misunderstood how foreign keys work - they are constraints and will not generate a user_id for you. A FK simply checks for existence in the referred table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in your user_id field does not have defalult value that's why it thrown error use like below your insert will work

```
INSERT INTO phone_numbers (user_id,phone_number) VALUES (1,'226');
```

Comment: Shouldnt the user_id field be auto generated since its a foreign key  ?

Comment: @Derek  how user_id will generate auto?

Comment: it wouldnt, i would have to refer to the foreign key value using php code when doing an insert